# Inserting url link into Gtk::TextBuffer

Tags: ruby, hyperlink, web, gtk, ruby-gnome2

I work on GUI project(http://smartdict.net) based on [ruby-gnome2](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/).
I want to insert a web link into [Gtk::TextBuffer](http://ruby-gnome2.sourceforge.jp/hiki.cgi?Gtk%3a%3aTextBuffer) element. How can I do that?

It's a ruby project but solutions on C or Python would be useful as well.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I did it:

As Micah said, you create a tag that makes the text look like a link (blue and underlined).  Then connect a signal to the TextView, so when the user clicks on it, it will call a method to open the url.  You'll need to devise a way for the method to know the link to open by keeping track of them in an array, or parsing the link based on the cursor position.  That part is up to you.

```
class myTextView  < Gtk::TextView

  def initialize
    signal_connect("button_release_event") { open_url() }   
    buffer.create_tag("blue", { "foreground" => "#0000FF", "underline" => Pango::UNDERLINE_SINGLE  })
    start_iter, end_iter = get_line_iters()
    buffer.apply_tag("blue", start_iter, end_iter)
  end

  def open_url()
     # open link here
  end

end
```

This is a standard Gtk solution.  I would suggest using visualruby:

http://visualruby.net

Comment: I like the simplicity of this. I did not think of checking for mouse-button-events. When I read it, the rest was simple to do (I have to custom parse the whole buffer anyway). By the way, what happened to visual ruby?

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't done this myself, I would imagine you could do it 2 ways:

1. Style the text yourself (blue with an underline) using text tags and handle the launching of the URL yourself.
2. Use a `gtk_text_buffer_insert_child_anchor` to specify where in the buffer to insert the link, and then `gtk_text_view_add_child_at_anchor` to insert a `GtkLinkButton` into the text view.

Comment: Hi Micah.  Thanks for your great tutorials on adding GUIs to ruby.  You inspired me to write visualruby.net.  Your tutorial was my first exposure to it.  Thanks!